# Getting avoiding locked SELECT:s in MySQL when using MyISAM

Tags: mysql, myisam

MyISAM uses table level locking which means that SELECT:s are blocked while INSERT/UPDATE:s are running.

To mitigate the problem of blocked SELECT:s I've been recommended to configure MySQL with these parameters:

- `low_priority_updates=1`
- `concurrent_insert=2`

What are the drawbacks of using `low_priority_updates=1` and `concurrent_insert=2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [great post from the MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/06/17/using-myisam-in-production/) which covers some of this

> **Lock priorities**. By default MySQL treats updates as higher priority
>   operations. You can use SELECT
>   HIGH_PRIORITY or UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY
>   to adjust that or you can simply set
>   low_priority_updates option. Anyway
>   default behavior means any UPDATE
>   statement which is blocked by long
>   running select will also block further
>   selects from this table – they will
>   have to wait until UPDATE is executing
>   which is waiting on SELECT to
>   complete. This is often not accounted
>   for and people think – “OK. I write my
>   script so it does short updates so it
>   will not block anything” – it still
>   may cause total block if there are
>   long selects running.

Another [post benchmarks concurrent_inserts](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/06/13/myisam-concurrent-insert/) and highlights possible downsides, though the post is 3 years old now.